# Objects and casting java

Tags: java, object, casting, extend

I was given this statement for homework.

Mammal pet = new Dog ();

Samoyed s = pet;

we were given a diagram like so:

Animal ---> Vertebrate ---> Mammal ---> Dog ---> Husky, Samoyed, Beagle

my understanding is that the code isn't valid and cannot be cast. Mammal refers to a Dog object and a Samoyed type is not in Dog or Mammal.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a child reference in a parent object but reverse is not true. First statement is valid as Dog is a child of Mammal. But second statement is incorrect as you are trying to a parent object of Mammal to its child reference Samoyed.

Basically JVM uses the concept of parent object to hold any child reference for polymorphism. Imagine a scenario where you have to design a method which can take an input of any kind of Animal. You can simply write testMethod(Animal animal), this method can accept any object of type Animal or its childs(which are also animal because they inherit).
If this feature is not available then you will end up writing different methods for different kind of animals.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
Samoyed s = pet;
```

will produce a compile time error since pet is a Mammal and a Mammal is not necessarily a Samoyed. But if you explicitly cast it

```
Samoyed s = (Samoyed)pet;
```

there will be no compile error. Nevertheless this line will throw a ClassCastException at runtime because the actual class of pet is Dog and Dog is not a subclass of Samoyed

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid cast since it is attempting to assign an instance of `Dog` to a variable declared as type `Samoyed`.  Your assumption is correct.

Comment: @TylerPierog Does this help?  I just reread your question I misread it the firs time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the **pet** is a big object, when you use

> Samoyed s = pet;

you should cast it, liks this

> Samoyed s = (Samoyed)pet;

Of course, it may loose some info.